# expdend array on same value

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 18
        [seller_id] => 1
        [item_name] => test1
        [price] => 10.00
        [username] => user 
        [ship_price] => 10.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 16
        [seller_id] => 1
        [item_name] => test2
        [price] => 10.00
        [username] => user
        [ship_price] => 20.00
    )
```

i get this array after foreach :

```
 foreach($result as $i => $row){

    $row[$i]["item_id"]          = $row["PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID"];
    $row[$i]["seller_id"]        = $row["PRODUCTS_SELLER_ID"];
    $row[$i]['item_name']        = $row['PRODUCTS_ITEM_NAME'];
    $row[$i]['price']            = $row['PRODUCTS_PRICE'];
    $row[$i]['username']         = $row['username'];
    $row[$i]['ship_price']       = $row['ship_price'];

    }
```

How can i expdend the array if the "seller_id" is the same, 
i just want to group all the data that are belong to the "seller_id" in the same array key.

i want to get something like this: (sorry if i have an error)

```
 Array
 (
 ["seller_id"] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
        [item_id] => 18
        [seller_id] => 1
        [item_name] => test1
        [price] => 10.00
        [ship_price_value] => 10.00
        [username] => user 
        [ship_price] => 10.00

        [1] => Array
        [item_id] => 16
        [seller_id] => 1
        [item_name] => test2
        [price] => 10.00
        [ship_price_value] => 10.00
        [username] => user
        [ship_price] => 20.00
    )
```

)

Comment: This is a *may-be-your-requirement* solution. After the `foreach` loop, do this:  `$seller_array = array(); $seller_array['seller_id'] = $row; var_dump($seller_array);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have 2 Options on how to solve this. The First would be to generate the desired Array Structure within your initial `foreach()`Loop. This means you have to do this only once. The Code for this option would look something like the Code Snippet below.

**NOTE:** *The Key `seller_id` is not added as a `string`; instead, the seller_id in the Key is simply the numeric `seller_id` for items that have the similar `seller_ids`. This was intentional because, if you tried to use the string-key `seller_id` and you have items with different `seller_ids`; you can be sure of Data-Loss since subsequent Data would override previous ones — the Keys being static, identical and the same `[seller_id]`: so keep that in mind as well...*

```
<?php

    $arrSellerRows              = [];

    foreach($result as $i => $row){
        $temp                       = [];
        $sellerID                   = $row["PRODUCTS_SELLER_ID"];
        $temp[$i]["item_id"]        = $row["PRODUCTS_ITEM_ID"];
        $temp[$i]["seller_id"]      = $sellerID;
        $temp[$i]['item_name']      = $row['PRODUCTS_ITEM_NAME'];
        $temp[$i]['price']          = $row['PRODUCTS_PRICE'];
        $temp[$i]['username']       = $row['username'];
        $temp[$i]['ship_price']     = $row['ship_price'];

        if(!array_key_exists($sellerID, $arrSellerRows)){
            $arrSellerRows[$sellerID]   = [];
            $arrSellerRows[$sellerID][] = $temp;
        }else{
            $arrSellerRows[$sellerID][] = $temp;
        }
    }
```

> The Second option would require that you take the resulting Array from your initial `foreach()` Loop and then process it a little further to get the desired Structure. This would not be efficient since it implies using 2 `Loops` for something that could be achieved with just one, single `Loop`:

```
<?php


    $array      = [
        [
            'item_id'       => 18,
            'seller_id'     => 1,
            'item_name'     => 'test1',
            'price'         => 10.00,
            'username'      => 'user',
            'ship_price'    => 10.00,
        ],
        [
            'item_id'       => 16,
            'seller_id'     => 1,
            'item_name'     => 'test2',
            'price'         => 10.00,
            'username'      => 'user',
            'ship_price'    => 20.00,
        ],
    ];


    function groupBySellerID($array){
        $arrSellerRows  = [];
        foreach($array as $iKey=>$arrData){
            $sellerID   = $arrData['seller_id'];
            if(!array_key_exists($sellerID, $arrSellerRows)) {
                $arrSellerRows[$sellerID]   = [];
                $arrSellerRows[$sellerID][] = $arrData;
            }else{
                $arrSellerRows[$sellerID][] = $arrData;
            }
        }
        return $arrSellerRows;
    }

    var_dump( groupBySellerID($array) );
    //YIELDS:::
    array (size=1)
      1 => // THIS NUMBER REPRESENTS THE SELLER_ID (WHICH IS 1)
        array (size=2)
          0 =>
            array (size=6)
              'item_id' => int 18
              'seller_id' => int 1
              'item_name' => string 'test1' (length=5)
              'price' => float 10
              'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
              'ship_price' => float 10
          1 =>
            array (size=6)
              'item_id' => int 16
              'seller_id' => int 1
              'item_name' => string 'test2' (length=5)
              'price' => float 10
              'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
              'ship_price' => float 20
```

Comment: Thanks i think i got it

Comment: Ok Poiz, but in case i want to output the result in html, how can i group the result by the seller_id, throw foreach loop.

Comment: @david2000  The Result is already grouped by `seller_id`. So if yo want to output some HTML from the resulting array, you just have to loop through that Array. But, keep in mind that since you now have a multi-dimensional Array, you may have to do that with nested loops. For example: `foreach($arrSellerRows as $sellerID=>$arrUniqueRows){ foreach($arrUniqueRows as $key=>$value){ // BUILD UP YOUR HTML MARKUP;  } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$seller = array();
foreach($result as $i => $row){
    $seller['seller_id'][] = $row;
}
var_dump($seller);
```

This code above can help you.